# Spanish highly qualified professional visa - spouse coverage?

Tags: visa, spain

I have a two part question. Context: Job offer in Spain; employer is willing to sponsor self & spouse “highly qualified professional” visa such that we can both live and work in country.

1. Is it standard for an employer to sponsor both you and your spouse (or is sponsoring your spouse atypical?)
2. What is the cost to the company to sponsor you? (I saw $190 online but this seems cheap…)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *‘sponsor’*? If you qualify for the visa, the rules allow dependents such as a spouse https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/londres/en/ServiciosConsulares/Paginas/Consular/Visado-para-trabajador-altamente-cualificado-y-para-traslado-intraempresarial.aspx

Comment: Ah I had understood visa processing to be expensive and “sponsoring” to mean handling the paperwork as well as fees on behalf of the individual. Maybe I don’t understand?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is it standard for an employer to sponsor both you and your spouse (or is sponsoring your spouse atypical?)

I am not that familiar with Spain but the way these things work in other European countries is that employers typically only need to formally “sponsor” the person they intend to employ. Depending on the country and exact visa category, that may mean that the employer has to pay a fee to be registered as a sponsor with the relevant agency, submit paperwork to show that they need someone with specific qualifications they couldn't recruit locally, etc.

Once an employee qualifies for some highly qualified migrant scheme, their spouse and minor children typically have a right to live with them. Even when there are additional income, housing, insurance, or language requirements, you don't need your employer's permission to get your family to join you.

Beyond this, employers sometimes offer additional relocation packages including legal advice to navigate the visa process, international movers, a consultant to find housing, money towards a private international school, etc. or simply a lump sum to help you get set up. What they offer and whether specific services cover your spouse is presumably up to them, not sure there is any “typical” package.

> 2. What is the cost to the company to sponsor you? (I saw $190 online but this seems cheap…)

The visa fee itself seems [even cheaper than this](https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/houston/es/Documents/TASA%20DE%20VISADOS%20%20Ingles%202023.pdf). You may have to pay to get some document translated and notarized and maybe pay some local processing fee depending on the consulate but I wouldn't necessarily expect to pay much more than this. This is typical for European countries even if there are countries where fees are noticeably higher (e.g. the UK, the Netherlands, Denmark).